# how do i improve cross join with 20,000 records?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `users (userid,student_no,name)` and `regd (semester,student_no)`.
`users` contain about 7,000 records and `regd` contains about 20,000 records. Sometimes there are entries in `regd` that are not in `users`.

How do I **quickly** select ALL entries in `users` that have entries in `regd` with semester = '2012-2'?
I tried this:

```
 SELECT * FROM  `regd` , users WHERE
      semester =  '2012-2' AND users.student_no = regd.student_no
```

But it is taking forever to load the queries if I have a tiny database. Every six months, about 10,000 entries are added to `regd` and about 2,500 entries are added to `users` each year.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to create indexes on regd.student_no and users.student_no

Comment: You want to improve command line or execution of this? I think that ou want to reduce time execution then you must redesign your database.

Comment: how do i create the index on regd.student_no and users.student_no? thank you!

Comment: [MySql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)... `CREATE INDEX idx_regd_student_no ON regd(student_no);` and `CREATE INDEX idx_users_student_no ON users(student_no);` The idx_* are up to you (it's just the name of the index). BTW - what are the keys on the tables?

Comment: 22K rows per year is by no means "big" - volume isn't your problem here.

Comment: To me it seems like there should be a primary key on one of these tables. Either way an index should be just about as good. Also I would go select users.*, to get even a faster result. But @AaronBertrand is right, I wouldn't consider 22k to be big by any means. Both tables having 22 million on the other hand. Now we're talking.

Comment: `userid` is the primary key for users and there is no primary key in `regd` should i also add a primary key for that?

Comment: you should put primary key (semester, student_no) on regd. (assuming, of course, that a student cannot register more than once in a semester)

Comment: i see. can you post your answer as answers so we can resolve this question? :)

Comment: @rationalboss primary keys usually have clustered indexes to back them up. Clustered indexes are about as good as you're going to do for performance when joining at that value. But to determine whether or not to put on on there, I'm unsure about what data is in these tables. You have to be the judge of that if that logically makes sense.

Comment: okay thank you everyone. i agree i need to redesign the tables... and probably a lot of other tables too. :)

Comment: @dko sometimes that's not quite true. A much narrower non-clustered index can often be the most efficient path, since fewer pages have to be read than with a clustered index (which carries along ALL of the data). But take with that a huge, fat IT DEPENDS.

Comment: @AaronBertrand agreed. I should have stated that key phrase at the end of "IT DEPENDS". However, frequently you are joining on the key to get something out of that table. You would have to include everything you want to get in the index otherwise you are going back to the main table to get the value. A single clustered index is the best general index but not the best optimized for a single query. Then there are even exceptions to that. so once again "IT DEPENDS"

Comment: @dko right, but you aren't always needing to go back to the table to get other values. When a non-clustered index also requires a lookup, sometimes it is more efficient to use the clustered index instead, but not always. Sometimes it is more efficient to add the required column(s) to the index key (or as includes).

Comment: @AaronBertrand :) yeah hence why I said "You would have to include everything you want to get in the index". I think we're saying the same thing, you're just better explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add indexes on the join columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_regd_student_no ON regd(student_no);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX idx_users_student_no ON users(student_no);
```

Also, if your tables don't have a PK, add one. In the case of regd, you can use PK = `(semester, student_no)`.

As other comments say, 22k records is not big, so I can only assume that you are without any decent index.

Hope this helps.